# HttpConnector in the webconsole of websphere

Tags: java, urlencode, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to set the HttpConnector parameters (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=command-integration-node-http-listener-parameters) in the webconsole of the Websphere.

Example: I want to set the 'relaxedQueryChars' parameter mentioned in this document in the webconsole. But I tried in the following links and its not available

1. Servers -> Server Types -> Websphere Application Servers -> {servername} ->
2. Applications -> Application Types -> Websphere enterprise applications -> {myapplicationname} ->

But not able to find the place where 'relaxedQueryChars' can be set for the application, Could someone help me with this please?